# meteor getting start tutorial where _id come from?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm following the good start tutorial
https://www.meteor.com/try/5

Can anyone tell me where this._id come from

I don't see any in the html template

### Template

```
<template name="task">
  <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
    <button class="delete">&times;</button>

    <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />

    <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
  </li>
</template>
```

### Js

```
Template.task.events({
    "click .toggle-checked": function () {
      // Set the checked property to the opposite of its current value
      Tasks.update(this._id, {$set: {checked: ! this.checked}});
    },
    "click .delete": function () {
      Tasks.remove(this._id);
    }
  });
```

I used to see the id in the html so .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in the tutorial:

> Inside the event handlers, this refers to an individual task object.

In general, `this` inside event handlers refers to the data context used to render the element the event is taken place upon.

**EDIT**

I realized my answer may not be that good to a beginner. Let me try again.

Look at where [the template is inserted](https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos/blob/4e6f9494c895eff43fe26167a7b803a24c35854e/simple-todos.html#L17). It's inside an `#each` block, and `#each` blocks change the data context to the document in the collection. In the task template, the data context is never changed (it can be changed with the `#each` and `#with` blocks), so `this` inside the event handlers will refers to the document used to render the template.